# React Native: performant rendering of an image based newsfeed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What are the best practices for rendering an image based newsfeed in react native?

I've got a very simple newsfeed where each story has a cover image and then a star rating (composed of 1-5 images). On initial render, the images appear to be loaded in random order and it looks awful and non-native.

[Here's a 7s video showing the screen transition and render.](https://vid.me/qu7m)

Is there any way to control the order in which the images render, or not to render a story until the whole block is loaded?

If it helps, the code is below. Using IncrementalListView to render the rows. Release build, iOS 9.3, iPhone 6. Each cover image is ~55kb JPG, and the star is ~3kb PNG. Both images are packaged into the bundle.

**UPDATE 3/31**

I changed the code to use IncrementalListView instead of rendering directly into ScrollView, but this hasn't helped. The problem seems to be with how images are decoded and rendered, not with how rows are rendered.

```
class DiscoverRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let images = {
      wide: {
        data: require('../img/img-wide.jpg'),
        height: 200,
        width: 376
      }
    };
    let title = this.props.event.name;
    let date = "Tomorrow";
    let place = this.props.event.venue.name;
    const newHeight = images.wide.height / images.wide.width * screenWidth;
    return (

        <View style={[rowStyles.cell]}>
          <View style={{ borderRadius: 15 }}>
            <Image resizeMode={'stretch'} source={images.wide.data} style={[rowStyles.thumbnail]} />
            <View style={[rowStyles.annotationsContainer]}>
              <View style={rowStyles.textContainer}>
                <AHStarRating starColor={gConstants.themeColor} disabled rating={4.5} style={{ width: 100 }} />
                <AHText style={rowStyles.title}>{title}</AHText>
                <AHText style={rowStyles.date}>{date}</AHText>
              </View>
              <View style={rowStyles.commentsContainer}>
                <Image source={require('../img/chat.png')}
                  style={{ width: 36, height: 36,
                    tintColor: gConstants.themeColor,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                />
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._poop}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../img/heart.png')}
                    style={{ width: 36, height: 36,
                      tintColor: gConstants.themeColor,
                      backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                  />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class DiscoverPage extends React.Component {

  static relay = {
    queries: { viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer }` },
    fragments: {
      viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Viewer {
          events {
            id
            name
            venue {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.setState({ renderPlaceholderOnly: false });
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.relayLoading) {
      const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
      this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(nextProps.viewer.events),
      });
    }
  }

  _renderRow(event: Object, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
      return <DiscoverRow
        onPress={() => Actions.event({ event })}
        key={`comment-${rowID}`} event={event}
      />;
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.relayLoading || this.state.renderPlaceholderOnly) {
      return <View><AHText>Relay loading</AHText></View>;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <AHNavBar title={'Discover'} leftTitle={""} rightImage={require('../img/filter.png')} />
          <IncrementalListView
            initialListSize={3}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
            renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} 
            style={styles.separator} />}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing with a [ListView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) instead of a [ScrollView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)?

Comment: This was a great idea, thanks, but it did move the needle w.r.t. the image loading speed. See updated code

Answer (score 0):

You should implement with a [ListView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) instead of a [ScrollView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html). [ListView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) has performance optimizations that improve scrolling performance.

From the [ListView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) section in the [React Native Docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/):

> There are a few performance operations designed to make ListView
>   scroll smoothly while dynamically loading potentially very large (or
>   conceptually infinite) data sets

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried ListView and @notbrent's IncrementalListView, no big improvement. I'll update my code above to the latest that I'm using.

Comment: I assume you're still seeing the performance issues in a release build? I commonly come across performance issues in development mode that are not present in release builds.

Comment: Yes, I am. [I uploaded a new video](https://vid.me/qu7m) showing what it currently looks like, iOS 9.3, iPhone 6, release build. It's slightly improved over the previous, but it still looks decidedly non-native.